# Show that $O_k$ is a principal ideal domain if and only if

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraic number field.cShow that $O_k$ is a principal ideal domain if and only if it satisfies the following condition: for every $\alpha\in k$, but $\alpha\not\in O_k$,there are $\beta,\gamma\in O_{k}$ such that $0<|\alpha\beta-\gamma|<1$. I want to prove $h(k)=1$. But I don't know how to find $\beta$，$\gamma$。

Comment: What you describe sounds like a slightly modified version of the idea of a Dedekind-Hasse norm.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind%E2%80%93Hasse_norm. This is discussed in Ireland & Rosen's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory".  Also see Theorem 49 in Pete Clark's file http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/factorization2010.pdf.

Comment: thanks so much.